# C how to get stdin from pipe and get user input in the same program (or clear stdin during execution?)

Tags: c, linux, input, fgets, getchar

I have a C program for linux where the user is intended to pipe information into the program (`echo "hello\nworld" | cprogram`), and then interactively search through that information. This requires that the program be able to first read from stdin, and then scan over the users keystrokes while the program is running in the terminal.

The problem is that I am not able to do both at once. I have setup the input system using `termios` for unbuffered input, and it gets the information piped into the program using `fgets`. Both parts work in isolation, but chaos ensues when they're called in the same program.

The program looks something like this currently

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void read_stdin() {
    char buf[BUFSIZ];

    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin) != NULL) {
               // save buf
        }
}

int main() {
    int i;
    char key = 0;
    struct termios old_tio, new_tio;

    read_stdin(); // reads info piped into program with fgets. reads until fgets returns NULL

    /* setup terminal (mostly copied from a termios example i found) */
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &old_tio);
    new_tio = old_tio;
    new_tio.c_lflag &= (~ICANON & ~ECHO);
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &new_tio);

    while (key != '\n') {
        key = getchar();
        printf("%d", key);
    }

    /* reset terminal */
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &old_tio);

    return 0;
}
```

read_stdin works as expected in isolation, but combined with the code for reading input, it will not pick up any input.

The code for reading inputs works as expected so long as there is no info being piped into the program. If there is, then it will infinitely output -1 or 255. It also doesn't work at all (even if no info is piped in) when read_stdin is ran. In that case, (obviously) read_stdin takes over the whole program.

Is there any way for me to fix this issue? Can I clear the stdin before trying to read keys from it?

Comment: You either use uring/epoll/select/poll to monitor your file descriptors then process whatever input you get from any of them.  Often you make the file descriptors non-blocking and handle writes in the same event loop.  The other approach have a thread concurrent thing you want to do.

Comment: Your stdin is either a terminal or a pipe. It cannot be both at the same time. If you need it to be both at different times, you need to do something about it. On Linux, you may want to `fd=open("/dev/tty", O_RDONLY)` and then `dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO)`.